# How come the input data get two extra spaces at the end?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to solve a programming problem using nodejs. 
I have used an event named **data** which will get triggered when user input data.

But the problem is the input data is appended with 2 more spaces.

For Example: When the user enters "amit"
The value received is "amit  " (2 extra spaces)

Code Snippet is attached below:

```
    function containUniqueChar2(input) {

    let set = 0;

    console.log(`${input.length}`)

    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        let val = input.charCodeAt(i) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0);

        if ((set & (1 << val)) > 0) return false

        set |= (1 << val)
    }

    return true
}

var stdin = process.openStdin();

stdin.addListener("data", function (d) {

    const input = d.toString()

    console.log(input.length)

    let isUnique = containUniqueChar1(input.toLowerCase())

    if (isUnique) {
        console.log('All Characters are Unique.')
    } else {
        console.log('String contain duplicate characters.')
    }

});

stdin.on('end', () => {
    process.exit()
});
```

Comment: I've tried to print the object d using JSON.stringify() and it shows that the after the input string \r and \n is appended to the string and when I set the encoding type to 'utf-8' I still get the same behavior.
Is there any way to avoid this behavior or any logical reasoning why is this happening.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see from the nodejs docs why it would be adding whitespace, you can certainly trim the whitespace, but I don't think that's the solution you're looking for.

> const input = d.toString().trim()